# Blocks overlapping floats but content wraps

Tags: css, css-float, block

I have a layering issue with a site that I can't seem to figure out how to get around.

Essentially, I have a float:right div that contains some linked images and a bunch of block divs on the same page (in the same wrapper). The text (content) all wraps as expected, but the block elements overlap the floated elements making the image links non-clickable. It becomes quite obvious when viewed using chrome/firebug/whatever that the blocks are getting in the way of the floats but nothing I have tried as yet has floated them to the top.

example from: http://wanganuilibrary.recollect.co.nz/nodes/view/280
[image: example of overlap]

What I need is a way of allowing the links on the images in the float to be clickable. The float can have a set width but not height, and the rest of the content needs to be free flowing and wrap under the float if/when required, so no forced padding or margins, e.g.: http://wanganuilibrary.recollect.co.nz/nodes/view/1519

Any ideas on how this could be achieved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually columns like this are built using floats.

The `left` content column would be `float: left` with a set width.

The `right` content would be `float: right` with a smaller width.

Otherwise you can set the `z-index` of the anchors around the images to higher than the other content,

Comment: can't use fixed widths and z-index has no effect :(

Comment: Uh, huh? OP has overlapping content so if he's *not* using fixed widths, `z-index` will control the layering. Using a `z-index` on a fixed-width element works fine...

Comment: z-index has been experimented with, setting to high numbers and other elements to auto or low numbers but the float still floats 'under' the other blocks on the page. I agree that this should work, but it just doesn't.

Comment: Are you inspecting the dom elements to see what z-index is being applied? You need to be sure you're using `position` otherwise z-index won't apply.

Comment: `position: relative` and `z-index` combined seems to have hit the nail on the head!!!!!  Will give it a full and proper test but initial tests are positive!